# Inclusion of convex polytopes and embedding from $\ell_2$ to $\ell_\infty$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, random-matrices, geometric-probability, metric-embeddings

I would like to dig deeper into the problem posted [Probability that a convex shape contains the unit ball](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141571/probability-that-a-convex-shape-contains-the-unit-ball):

> If you pick n points uniformly at random from the surface of a d
>   dimensional sphere of radius r>1 with center at the origin, what is
>   the probability that the convex hull of these points contains the unit
>   ball (of dimension d) centered at the origin?

In the comment session I saw an exponential lower bound:

> ...for $\ell_2^d$ to well-embed into $\ell_\infty^m$ the dimension $m$
>   must be exponential in $d$...$m$ is at least $\exp(d/(64r^2))$...
>   Saying  that the convex symmetric hull of $n$ points can contain the
>   unit ball is the same as saying that $\ell_2^d$ embeds into
>   $\ell_\infty^m$ with distortion at most $r$.

I also came across [Smallest singular value of random matrices
and geometry of random polytopes](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~alexandr/OrganizedPapers/lprtlastlast.pdf). They consider a random matrix $\Gamma\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}$ where each entry is an i.i.d Gaussian. Let $K_m$ be the absolute convex hull of the rows of $\Gamma$, in theorem 4.2 and the following remark, they stated (I paraphrased) that:

> If $m$ is polynomial in $d$, then $P(K_m\supset
> C\sqrt{\beta\ln(m/d)}B_2^d)\geq1-\exp(-cd^\beta m^{1-\beta})$

These two statements somehow seem a little conflicting. The first statement says that you need exponentially many points in d to make the convex hull include a $\ell_2$ ball, while the second says only polynomially many would make the convex hull $K_m$ include a $\ell_2$ ball with high probability.

My understanding is that, if we write $\Gamma$ as the embedding, in the first statement, the row vector of $\Gamma$ is picked on a sphere, which is bounded, so it is harder to contain a $\ell_2$ ball, while in the second statement, we sample rows according to Gaussian, which is unbounded, so it's easier to contain a ball. Note that in both statement, we can control how large the included ball is.

If I understand correctly, [Asymptotic shape of a random polytope in a convex body](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123609002870) theorem 1.1 says that if each row of $\Gamma$ is uniformly picked in a ball, and if $m$ is only polynomial in $d$, then the best we can say is with high probability, $K_m$ contains a $\ell_2$ ball (the paper gives inclusion of $L_q$ centroid $Z_q$, but a scaled $\ell_2$ ball is included in $Z_q$  if $q>2$), but we can't describe how large the ball is, unless we make $m$ exponential in $d$, as stated by the first statemenet.

Thanks for any advice!