# What is the probability x triangles can be formed?

Tags: co.combinatorics

We have a stick of length $g$ which is dropped and is broken into $n$ pieces. The choice of the $n-1$ breaking points are chosen randomly and independently on the stick.

What is the probability that with $n$ breaks some number of triangles $x$ can be formed?

Note that we say that a triangle can be formed if some three lengths we choose satisfy the triangle inequality. A piece can be used in multiple triangles.

I'm not expecting a perfect solution but if you have any cases or something that'd be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of two breaks, one triangle, see the earlier MO question, [If you break a stick at two points chosen uniformly, the probability the three resulting sticks form a triangle is 1/4. Is there a nice proof of this?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2014/6094).
One answer there, by Michael Lugo, answers a more general 
question—not yours—but rather forming an $n$-gon rather than many triangles:

> One reference for a solution to this problem is Carlos d'Andrea and Emiliano Gomez, "The broken spaghetti noodle", *American Mathematical Monthly* 113 (2006), p. 555, [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27641981), [author's website](https://atlas.mat.ub.edu/personals/dandrea/emiliano_gomez.ps). More generally the probability that an interval broken at $n-1$ points chosen uniformly at random is broken into pieces which can be rearranged to form an $n$-gon is $1 - n/2^{n-1}$.